# Blow-ups of $ F $-regular varieties at points in general position and finite generation of the Cox ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, birational-geometry, frobenius-splitting

A variety $ X $ is $ F $-split if there exists an $ \mathcal{O}_{X} $-linear map $ \phi: F_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}) \to \mathcal{O}_{X} $ such that $ \phi \circ F^{\sharp} = \operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} $.  Such a map $ \phi $ is called a splitting.  A closed sub-scheme $ Y $ of $ X $ is compatibly split if there exists a splitting $ \phi $ such that $ \phi(F_{\ast}(\mathcal{I}_{Y})) \subseteq \mathcal{I}_{Y} $.  Note that $ \mathcal{I}_{Y} \subseteq \phi(F_{\ast}(\mathcal{I}_{Y})) $ already.

If $ X $ is a normal variety, then $ X $ if $ F $-regular if for all effective Weil divisors $ D $ there is an $ e \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \mathcal{O}_{X} \to F^{e}_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}) \to F^{e}_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)) $ splits.

If $ Z $ is a Mori Dream Space, then let $ \operatorname{cx}(Z) $ be the least natural number $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that the Cox ring of the blow-up of $ Z $ at $ n $-points in general position is not finitely generated.

If $ Z $ is an $ F $-regular, normal, projective variety, then let $ b(Z) $ be the least natural number $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that if $ W $ is the blow-up of $ Z $ at $ n $-points in general position, then $ -K_{W} $ is not big.

In https://mathoverflow.net/posts/439107/edit @KarlSchwede pointed out that if one keeps blowing up $ \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k} $ (which is $ F $-regular) at points in general position, then eventually one obtains a variety which is not $ F $-regular.  We know that by the time we have blown-up $ 9 $ points that $ -K_{W} $ is no longer big.  If $ W_{n} $ is the blow-up of $ \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k} $ at $ n $-points in general position, then I do not know if $ -K_{W_{n}} $ is still big for $ n<9 $ as I don't know if $ H^{1}(W_{n},-mK_{W_{n}}) $ vanishes for $ n<9 $ and $ m>>0 $.  If it does, then $ \operatorname{vol}(-K_{W_{n}})>0 $ for $ n<9 $ and $ b(\mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}) $ is exactly nine.

Needless to say, $ \operatorname{cx}(\mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}) $ is exactly nine by a result of Mukai.

If one looks at **Some Non-Finitely Generated Cox Rings** Jose Luiz Gonzalez and Kalle Karu, then in that paper Gonzales and Karu examine when the Cox ring of the blow-up of a weighted projective space at exactly one smooth point is not finitely generated.  On page 5 of that paper they give a few examples of weights $ (a:b:c) $ for which the Cox ring of $ \operatorname{Bl}_{e}(\mathbb{P}(a:b:c)) $ is not finitely generated.

Examples are $ (7:15:26), (7:17:29), (7:22:17) $.  A toric Bezout's theorem for weighted projective spaces (see **A Toric Proof of Bezout's Theorem for Weighted Projective Spaces** By Berndt Ivar Utstol Nodland) states that if $ E_{1},\dots,E_{n} $ are $ n $ torus invariant divisors on $ \mathbb{P}(q_{0}:\cdots:q_{n}) $, then $ E_{1}\cdots E_{n} = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{deg}(E_{i})\right)/(\prod_{j=0}^{n} q_{j}) $.  The anticanonical divisor of a weighted projective surface is $ -\sum_{i=1}^{3} D_{\rho_{i}} $.  Note that for all of these weighted projective spaces $ Z $ that $ (-K_{Z})^{2}<1 $.  As a result $ b(Z)=\operatorname{cx}(Z) $ for these weighted projective spaces.

Is it worth looking into this pattern, or does anyone know an example of an $ F $-regular, Mori dream space $ Z $ such that $ b(Z) \ne \operatorname{cx}(Z) $?

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field, blow-ups of the projective plane at $n<9$ points are del Pezzo surfaces (Fano), so their anticanonical divisor is ample.

Regarding the WPP case: Cutkosky (91) showed that these surfaces are MDS whenever $-K_X^2 >0$, which explains your observation regarding Gonzalez and Karu's result.

Comment: Let me add: Cutkosky's result is a sufficient, yet not necessary, condition for these blow-ups to be MDS. See for example the work of Gonzalez-Anaya, Gonzalez and Karu.

Comment: What does (91) refer to?

Comment: The year, here's the reference: Cutkosky, Steven Dale. "Symbolic algebras of monomial primes." Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik 416 (1991): 71-90.